# 8th Wall XR XCode Build Error

Tags: xcode8, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, 8thwall-xr

I imported the XR plugin into my Unity project, generated the XCode project, then got a build error when trying to build the project in XCode:

```
ld: framework not found ARKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

All I've done so far is follow the instructions provided in the [documentation](https://docs.8thwall.com/xr/unity). Any ideas what could be going on? I'm currently using Unity 5.5.0 and XCode 8.3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look at the documentation link and it says supporting XCode 9 or above. I just tried and it works for me on XCode 9.